# How to control haxis dataformat in google visualization chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using the Google visualization chart in my application for drawing a line chart. It works great except one thing in the hAxis the entered number converts itself to thousands like below. I know this is happening because im trying to display huge numbers but still i would like to know if there is way to get around this?

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Degree Level');  
      data.addColumn('number', 'Graduate or professional degree');
      data.addColumn('number', "Bachelor's degree");
      data.addColumn('number', "Associate's degree");
      data.addColumn('number', "High school or vocational training");

      data.addRows([
        [2,  39758,93179, 78578,49141],
        [3,  100747, 300646, 220982,100456],
        [4,  49964,   68022, 21092,6943],
        [5,  150370, 124868, 27120,8204]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Education Report',
          subtitle: 'distributed by experience'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output** 
[image]

Can someone let me know how can i make the hAxis to display in number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to get the format that you want.

Either you use version 1 of the corecharts package :

so load the package like this :

```js
// instead of : google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
```

and call your chart like this :

```js
// instead of : var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
```

And you'll get what you want.

See a [demo jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/txLdq72j/).

Or alternatively,

Use version 1.1 of the package (you already do in your example) like this :

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
```

and then specify in your chart options the vAxis format like this :

```js
vAxis: { format: '###,###,###' },
```

and load the chart this way, so that the vAxis settings are taken into account :

```js
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

That'll work too.

See a [demo jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/h5zapd27/).

The problem here is that the way options are defined has changed from v.1 to v.1.1. So if you want to use the v.1.1 package you have to call google.charts.Line.convertOptions() for your options to be interpreted correctly.